# WordPress - Including an Advanced Custom Field (ACF) in a search through blog posts and displaying the fields in the search results

Tags: php, wordpress, search, advanced-custom-fields

I have a particularly tricky question to put forwards. Hopefully this doesn't become too niche that it cannot help everyone.

I have created a custom search that will only display results from a specified category. If you would like to do the same follow steps 1 & 2.

1. Create a form for a search:

Save it as advanced.php in the root of your theme / child theme. You will already have a search.php file in this directory.

/blog/ is the route to your blog posts - if you receive no results check this.

The value of cat_slug becomes your category in which it will search.

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/blog/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="post">
    <input id="search-case-study" class="search-case-study" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search..." name="s" />
    <input name="cat_slug" value="case-study" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

2. Add to functions.php:

   ```
   function advanced_search_query( $query ) {

   // check if search AND if "cat_slug" input was present
   if( $query->is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['cat_slug'] ) ) {

       // find the category by the slug passed in the input
       $term = get_category_by_slug( $_GET['cat_slug'] ); 
       // defensive check, in case the category could not be found
       if ( ! empty( $term->term_id ) ) {

           // get the category ID
           $cat_id = $term->term_id;
           // set the query argument to search within the category
           $query->set( 'cat', $cat_id );

       }

   }

   }
   ```

   add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query');

Now the search results are narrowed down. I need to adjust which elements of the post I can see.

At this point I have created my blogs relevant to this search with a custom template utilising ACF as you can see in my form the category has the slug 'case-study'. We don't require all the fields I have used. The fields relevant to the search are:
repeater - case_study_page_content
sub_fields - title
sub_fields - author
sub_fields - content

I have began editing my content.php file contained within the template-parts directory to display the results, this is looking like this:

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?> class="blog-post">

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="box-link"></a>

    <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />

    <h2>
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h2>

    <h3>
        <?php the_field('author'); ?>
    </h3>

    <!--
    <div>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    -->

</article>
```

This is where I have ran into my complication as I am unable to just call the_field('author'); into the results loop.

Has anyone else been able to successfully pull values from within ACF's used in a custom blog page template into the search results page?

Thanks so much in advance, this is a little above my brains capacity and any help provided will be massively appreciated. Jason.

Comment: is `author` inside a repeater?

Comment: you can use get_field() from acf

Comment: if `author` is inside the repeater, you need to get sub fields - just follow the documentation : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the direction of @Stender and @siddhesh - I have snapped out of my insanity.

I was under the impression I had to allow ACF to be searchable when in fact you can call them already. My content.php file now looks like this:

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?> class="blog-post">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="box-link"></a>

    <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />

    <h2>
      <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h2>

    <?php
        $case_study = get_field('case_study_page_content');
    ?>

    <?php if( $case_study ): ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('case_study_page_content') ): the_row();
            $case_study_author = get_sub_field('author');
        ?>
            <h3>
                <?php echo $case_study_author; ?>
            </h3>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

</article>
```